# Why the 14 most significant bits of 17612864 is 67?

Tags: algorithm, computation-theory, clrs

At the bottom of Page 264 of CLRS, the authors say after obtaining `r0 = 17612864`, the 14 most significant bits of `r0` yield the hash value `h(k) = 67`. I do not understand why it gives 67 since 67 in binary is `1000011` which is 7 bits.

**EDIT**
In the textbook:
  As an example, suppose we have `k = 123456, p = 14, m = 2^14 = 16384, and w = 32`. Adapting Knuth's suggestion, we choose A to be the fraction of the form `s/2^32` that is closest to `(\sqrt(5) - 1) / 2`, so that `A = 2654435769/2^32`. Then `k*s = 327706022297664 = (76300 * 2^32) + 17612864`, and so `r1 = 76300 and r0 = 17612864`. The 14 most significant bits of `r0` yield the value `h(k)=67`.

Comment: I do not know how possible it would be, but including here a bit more of the context instead of just the page number on the book might help to find someone that can answer your question.

Comment: Look at the figure 11.4 (at the top of the page 264), `w` is 32, you extract `p` (14) bits from the left (most significant) of a 32-bit number.

Comment: Thank you! Now I can understand this figure.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`17612864` = `0x010CC040` =

```
0000 0001 0000 1100 1100 0000 0100 0000
```

Most significant 14 bits of that is

```
0000 0001 0000 11
```

Which is `0x43`, which is `67`

Also:

```
int32 input = 17612864;
int32 output = input >> (32-14); //67
```

Comment: I did not take the machine word size into account. Indeed, the authors mention before that suppose the word size of the machine is w bits and that k fits into a single word. I did not fully understand its meaning.

Answer (score 3):

In a 32 bit world

17612864 = 00000001 00001100 11000000 01000000 (binary)

top fourteen bits = 00000001 000011 = 67

Comment: Yes! The authors do mention that the machine is w (w = 32 here) bits.